# How to get page name with webBrowser

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, webbrowser-control

Try to code with WPF. Currently I want to implement a simple `webBrowser`, and now I'm stuck. I want to get name of opened page (Every tab has name according to opened page), but I can't find the solution. In C# I can use this code:

```
TabControl.SelectedTab.Text = webBrowser.Url.Host.ToString();
```

But with WPF it doesn't work.
What is solution to find page name with WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please try like this,**

```
TabControl.SelectedTab.Text = webBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri;
```